# how to change adobe reader default Page Display?

Tags: adobe-reader, display-settings, default-settings

When I read a document in Adobe Reader, it's always in Two Page Scrolling.
So I want that to be the default Page Display setting.
Instead of Single Page View.
Path: View -> Page Display -> Two Page Scrolling.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### How do I change adobe reader's default Page Display?

- Goto `Edit` -> `Preferences` -> `Accessibility`.
- Select `Always use Page Layout Style`
- Choose the Layout Style you want.
- Press OK

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this! So sodding annoying the two page view every time! Great to have it on single page all the time now. I find the setting below it "Always use Zoom Setting" still gets ignored though. I set it to 100% and still get it filling the screen every time (111% in my case). At least it's only Cmd-1 now every time instead of having to use the page display menu. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I frequently find that Adobe Reader will not keep the custom defaults I set for Page Display. I suspect it is because I am running on a terminal server and the 'defaults' are not getting saved into the correct location.

I have resorted to pressing ALT, v, p ,c when I open a file to get single page continuous scroll mode.